# Image preview opens for duplicated div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a function that uploads and image and adds a preview to this image, and i have two buttons, when i click on the first one it clicks on the input type file and opens it, and the second one duplicates the div, how can i duplicate this div and change it's id's or classes? and after duplicating it how can i make the buttons work for the new duplicated div not the original one only? here is my code:

```js
$(function() {
$("input:file").change(function() {
if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;
reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
}
});
});

function imageIsLoaded(e) {
 $('#ImgUpload').attr('src', e.target.result);
};

$('.uploadimg').click(function(){
    $('input:file').click();
});
```

```css
input{
display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="uploader">
<button type="button" class="uploadimg">Open uploader</button>
<input type="file">
<img id="ImgUpload" alt="Your Image"/>
<br>
<br>
</div>
<button type="button">Duplicate button</button>
```

Comment: `var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");`

Comment: @Sank6 can you clarify that to me?

Comment: Is there a problem with the solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Duplication the element and the script together will be helpful
check this i got it working as you want (took me a good time)

```js
var i = 0;
$('#inputfile' + i).change(function() {
  console.log(i);
  if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
  }
});


function imageIsLoaded(e) {

  console.log(i);
  $('#ImgUpload' + i).attr('src', e.target.result);
};

function upload(id) {
  $('#' + id).click();
};

$('#duplicate').click(function() {
  i++;
  var newelement =

    '<br><div class="uploader">' +
    '<button type="button" class="uploadimg" onclick="upload(\'inputfile' + i + '\')">Open uploader</button>' +
    '<input type="file" id="inputfile' + i + '" >' +
    '<img id="ImgUpload' + i + '" alt="Your Image" />' +
    '<br><br>' +
    '<script>$(\'#inputfile' + i + '\').change(function() { ' +
    'console.log(i);' +
    'if (this.files && this.files[0]) {' +
    'var reader = new FileReader();' +
    'reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;' +
    'reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);' +
    '}' +
    '});</sc'+'ript></div>';
  $(newelement).insertBefore("#duplicate");

});
```

```css
input {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="uploader">
  <button type="button" onclick="upload('inputfile0')">Open uploader</button>
  <input type="file" id="inputfile0">
  <img id="ImgUpload0" alt="Your Image" />
  <br>
  <br>
</div>
<button type="button" id="duplicate">Duplicate button</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

One common problem I see with this file previews are that most of them are unable to correctly render [jpg's rotated with exif orientation](https://github.com/recurser/exif-orientation-examples)

The second thing is that it's better to use [URL.createObjectURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) rather then using a base64 dataURL. That also raises an other issue and that is that most developers forget to [revoked](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/revokeObjectURL) objectURL's

That is why i have created [Screw-FileReader](https://github.com/jimmywarting/Screw-FileReader) so you can easily call `blob.image()` and get a image back with a object url that is automatically revoked and also has a exif auto-rotation built in using canvas.

```js
var $file = $('#filepicker').on('change', preview);

$('.uploader button').click(function() {
  $file.click()
})

function preview(evt) {
  var preview = document.querySelector('.preview')
  
  Array.from(this.files).forEach(function(file) {
    file.image().then(function(img) {
      preview.appendChild(img)
    }, function() {
      // err not an image...
    })
  })
}
```

```css
input {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jimmywarting/Screw-FileReader/master/index.js"></script>

<div class="uploader">
  <button type="button">Open uploader</button>
  <input id="filepicker" type="file" multiple accept="image/*">
  <div class="preview"></div>
</div>
```

the third thing i notis with Soltani Neji answer was that when you click dublicate button before the first upload button it dose unexpected things. it don't keep track of the index so well.

Now to my suggestions: Use the `multiple` attribute instead and just have one button to make it simpler. it also helps to add the `accept="image/*"` to filter out only images

Answer (score 0):

you can append the element instead of duplicating it. you can change the classes and ids using variables.

```
$('.duplicate').click(function() {
  var newClass="new-class";
  var toAppendElement = '<div class="uploader">' +
    '<button type="button" class="uploadimg '+newClass+'">Open uploader</button>' +
    '<input type="file">' +
    '<img id="ImgUpload" alt="Your Image" />' +
    '<br><br></div>';
  $(".cloned").append(toAppendElement);
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8h3gcyhz/

Comment: Try appending many divs and click on the upload button and see what happens please

Comment: well, thats because of  this  code$(document).on('click', '.uploadimg', function() {
  $('input:file').click();
});

Comment: I know, and a part of my question was how to make this function work to only one div not all of them

Comment: change it  to
  $(document).on('click', '.uploadimg', function() {
  $(this).siblings('input:file').click();
});
http://jsfiddle.net/8h3gcyhz/2/