# picture pre-visualisation for multiple files

Tags: javascript

I have a code to allow to pre-visualise the picture selected in a form.

However it doesn't work, what shoul I change?

```
<input type="file" id="profile-img1" data-idpreview="image1">
<div id="image1"></div>

<input type="file" id="profile-img2" data-idpreview="image2">
<div id="image2"></div>


function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var idPreview = $(input).attr('data-idpreview');
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
      $('#' + idPreview).css('backgroundImage', "url(" + e.target.result + ")" );
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}
```

Comment: you are not calling readURL in anyway. You need to set up the event listener. `input.onchange = readURL`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47005651/1008999